# Out of memory error while downloading google storage object

Tags: java, out-of-memory, google-cloud-storage, google-api-java-client

I am trying to download a object from google storage and I get out of memory exception. I tried increasing my heapsize to -Xms512M -Xmx1024M but of no use. Below is my code :

```
public static void downloadToOutputStream(String bucketName, String objectName,
      OutputStream data) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    Storage storage = StorageFactory.getService();
    Storage.Objects.Get getObject = storage.objects().get(bucketName, objectName);
    getObject.getMediaHttpDownloader().setDirectDownloadEnabled(!IS_APP_ENGINE);
    getObject.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(data); 

  }
```

I understand it's because I am writing to outputstream but is there a way I can chunk the download or avoid this error..?

Comment: The issue is probably setDirectDownloadEnabled. If that's true, it will buffer the entire object in memory. How big is the object, and what type of OutputStream are you using?

Comment: It's ByteArrayOutputStream and object downloaded could be of maximum 800 MB.

Comment: That's probably the issue then, you have a maximum 1024MB of heap space, and then you're using 800MB for the output, and then probably another copy of the data for the download. Depending on you're goal, changing to a FileOutputStream and not setting DirectDownloadEnabled would likely fix the problem, but you'd have the data on a file instead of a byte array.

Comment: That does it. Thanks..!!

Comment: not setting the DirectDownloadEnabled does not work for me. the way I fixed it is to select right kind of OutputStream to use it. I get rid of ByteArrayOutputStream so it uses FileOutputStream. Now I have no memory upper bound restriction and definitely increasing JVM memory is not a permanent solution.